# Find the index corresponding to the max value of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy.array` of data called f, I know the max value in it is `f_max=max(f)` but I would like to know the index in the array corresponding to the maximum value.

I tried:

```
count = 0
while (f[count]!=fmax)
    conto ++
```

but I receive an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: On the syntax error: you need a `:` at the end of the `while` statement, and use `count += 1`, but the answer below is the right way to do it.

Comment: @Caos note that I have edited your question and included the `numpy` tag **based on the information below that you are using a numpy array.** If this information is incorrect then please say so.

Comment: Yes! I confirm that I was using a numpy array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to find the `max` and then, look for its index.

```
>>> a = [1, 5, 2, 3, 4]
>>> val = max(a)
>>> a.index(val)
1
```

You could also use `enumerate` to get a list of indices and the values corresponding to them and choose the max among them.

```
>>> list(enumerate(a))
[(0, 1), (1, 5), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
>>> index, _ = max(enumerate(a), key = lambda x: x[1])
>>> index
1
```

Comment: Doing this I receive: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: @Caos: You should have mentioned you have a Numpy Array.

Comment: @Caos: You should use `np.argmax` in that case.

Comment: Sorry I am new to python ad I thought I was using a list

Comment: This solution only works to show the first instance of a max, is there a more robust solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you're already using numpy, you can do this with argmax().

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 5, 2, 6, 3])

index = a.argmax()
```